# No background photo in desktop workspace in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, desktop-background

My workspace background in the ubuntu 14.04 desktop is black.  Any attempt to change the wallpaper results only in changing the wallpaper on my login screen.  I evidently caused this when I tried to have different wallpapers in each of the 4 workspaces.  The black background is no problem for me other than I would like to have a background photo.

**Added to description of problem:** I have attempted to correct the problem by unchecking enable workspaces and rebooting, then changing the wallpaper.. same result.  The wallpaper changes on the login screen, but the desktop screen is black.  If I knew where the graphical login looks to find the background for the desktop/workspace, that would help.

Answer (score 2):

Carl go to system settings, engage appearance, under the behaviour tab deselect  "enable workspaces"  then reboot. Go back to appearance and merely select one background pic or  logo. Go to behavior and select "enable workspaces" you should be good to go.